# Loop through array elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, for-loop, ios8

I am developing one app,in that i have used to send my contact numbers to the server through WebServices.Here i get the my contact numbers an array,but how can i send my contact array on for-loop.Here the services link .

```
http://project.in/project-contacts.php
```

parameter  `contact_numbers[]`

here below i tried code

```
NSString *postVarArrayString = @"";
    NSString *separator = @"?";
    for (int i=0; i<[_numberArray count]; i++) {
        if (i>0) {
            separator = @"&";
        }
        postVarArrayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@myArray[]=%ld", postVarArrayString, separator, (long)[[_numberArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];
    }

    // url
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                       @"http://project.in/project-contacts.php"
                                       @"%@"
                                       , postVarArrayString]
                  ];

    NSLog(@"qq=%@", [url absoluteString]);
```

here how can i send array of my contacts through WebServices.Can you please suggest me how can i send ,thank you.

Comment: Send whole array to the server.. Let the server side script do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Send a dictionary as a parameter so that your php script grabs those parameters with `$_POST` variable.

Example using **[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)** library.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"key1", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"value1", @"value2", nil];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: values Keys: keys];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your  server url"];
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"path" parameters:parameters];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
}];
[operation start];
```